# Function works with divs but not paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering why one piece of code is working when a div is used, but is not working when a paragraph is used. I appreciate any and all responses.

Working code:

HTML

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="myDiv">&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('div').not('#myDiv').css('background-color', '#000000');
```

See the working JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/w8fRk/

See the broken (oddly) JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/w8fRk/14/

Both involve the .not command in jQuery, and I'm actually a little embarrassed by my code's lack of functionality.

Comment: Please use the title as a descriptive summary. "Something has an issue" is not descriptive. Also it helps to explain what is supposed to happen, even if it seems obvious.

Comment: It would also be nice to post the code here or together so we can compare working and not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your operations are backwards.

```
$('p').not('#game0').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w8fRk/16/

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something ridiculous. I am just as embarrassed as when I posted this.

Comment: It happens. I'd be more embarrassed about your completely useless question title. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have your function calls in the wrong order. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').not('#game0').hide();
});
```